# 4 functions near identical, one works but the others dont no errors

Tags: python, cryptography, docx

I have 4 functions that should grab some text from a specific docx file that are highlighted `scan4<colour>` is the varialbe of the text, these functions are near identical but are searching and replacing different highglighted text, they print out the same but they dont replace the text

these are 2 functions of 4, the `yellow` one works while the `green` one doesnt
what the code does is it searches and replaces the text then encrypts then uses the encrypted string into the main document, the other does the exact same but searches for a different highlighted colour. I try to encrypt the first function works but the second one doesn't

This code searches for yellow encodes the text and then replaces it so the un-encrypted document shows the encrypted string of the contents

```
def securi1_key():
        file = open("C:/Users/devff/PycharmProjects/SecurityLevels/Stored Keys/Securi1.key", "rb")
        global key1
        key1 = file.read()
        file.close()


    def rewrite_yellow():
        securi1_key()
        save_yellow_text()
        #   get key from file
        file = open("C:/Users/devff/PycharmProjects/SecurityLevels/Stored Keys/Securi1.key", "rb")
        texty = scan4yellow.decode("utf-8")
        encodedy = texty.encode()

        #   encrypt message
        f = Fernet(key1)
        encryptedy = f.encrypt(encodedy)
        print(scan4yellow)
        print(scan4yellow.decode("utf-8"))
        document = docx.Document(f1)
        for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
            if scan4yellow.decode("utf-8") in paragraph.text:
                inline = paragraph.runs
                # loops for runs
                for i in range(len(inline)):
                    if scan4yellow.decode("utf-8") in inline[i].text:
                        text = inline[i].text.replace(scan4yellow.decode("utf-8"), encryptedy.decode("utf-8"))
                        inline[i].text = text
        document.save(f1)


    def save_yellow_text():
        securi1_key()
        fp = f1
        p = Path(fp)
        filename1 = p.stem

        storedtexty = filename1 + " Yellow Text"
        storedtextencryptedy = storedtexty + ".encrypted"
        list_of_files = os.listdir("C:/Users/devff/PycharmProjects/SecurityLevels/Stored Text/")

        if storedtexty in list_of_files:
            storedtexty = (storedtexty + "1")

        file = open("C:/Users/devff/PycharmProjects/SecurityLevels/Stored Text/" + storedtexty, "w+")
        file.write(scan4yellow.decode("utf-8"))

        input_file1 = ("C:/Users/devff/PycharmProjects/SecurityLevels/Stored Text/" + storedtexty)

        if storedtextencryptedy in list_of_files:
            storedtextencryptedy = (storedtextencryptedy + "1")

        output_file1 = ("C:/Users/devff/PycharmProjects/SecurityLevels/Stored Text/" + storedtextencryptedy)

        with open(input_file1, "rb") as f:
            data = f.read()

        fernet = Fernet(key1)
        encrypted = fernet.encrypt(data)

        with open(output_file1, "wb") as f:
            f.write(encrypted)

        file.close()
        os.remove(input_file1)
```

this code should do the exact same but for the colour green :

```
def securi2_key():
        file = open("C:/Users/devff/PycharmProjects/SecurityLevels/Stored Keys/Securi2.key", "rb")
        global key2
        key2 = file.read()
        file.close()


    def rewrite_green():
        securi2_key()
        save_green_text()
        #   get key from file
        file = open("C:/Users/devff/PycharmProjects/SecurityLevels/Stored Keys/Securi2.key", "rb")
        textg = scan4green.decode("utf-8")
        encodedg = textg.encode()
        print(encodedg)

        #   encrypt message
        f = Fernet(key2)
        encryptedg = f.encrypt(encodedg)
        print(encryptedg)

        document = docx.Document(f1)
        for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
            if scan4green.decode("utf-8") in paragraph.text:
                inline = paragraph.runs
                # loops for runs
                for i in range(len(inline)):
                    if scan4green.decode("utf-8") in inline[i].text:
                        text = inline[i].text.replace(scan4green.decode("utf-8"), encryptedg.decode("utf-8"))
                        inline[i].text = text
        document.save(f1)


    def save_green_text():
        securi2_key()
        fp = f1
        p = Path(fp)
        filename2 = p.stem

        storedtextg = filename2 + " Green Text"
        storedtextencryptedg = storedtextg + ".encrypted"
        list_of_files = os.listdir("C:/Users/devff/PycharmProjects/SecurityLevels/Stored Text/")

        if storedtextg in list_of_files:
            storedtextg = (storedtextg + "1")

        file = open("C:/Users/devff/PycharmProjects/SecurityLevels/Stored Text/" + storedtextg, "w+")
        file.write(scan4green.decode("utf-8"))
        print(scan4green.decode("utf-8") + "tested1")

        input_file2 = ("C:/Users/devff/PycharmProjects/SecurityLevels/Stored Text/" + storedtextg)

        if storedtextencryptedg in list_of_files:
            storedtextencryptedg = (storedtextencryptedg + "1")

        output_file2 = ("C:/Users/devff/PycharmProjects/SecurityLevels/Stored Text/" + storedtextencryptedg)

        with open(input_file2, "rb") as f:
            data = f.read()

        fernet = Fernet(key2)
        encrypted = fernet.encrypt(data)

        with open(output_file2, "wb") as f:
            f.write(encrypted)

        file.close()
        os.remove(input_file2)
```

I should have some incoherent string replace the actual text and the actual text saved in another file encrypted, but all this does is work for the first yellow function but not the green function

Ideally it should take the text from the read in file, make a copy write it out to a file and encrypt that then take the string of encryption from that and replace it where it was in the read in file, but it only works for the yellow code while the green and the other code which are near identical do not work

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer, what I changed has nothing to do with the code I provided but when I read in the text it was `scan4green = (word.find(tag_t).text.encode('utf-8').lower())`. this apparently caused it not to work properly but the scan4yellow did work because i didn't have `.lower()` attached to the end.